# styling an asp:button server control

Tags: .net, asp.net

I by no means a .NET developer but I have a task to style "CSS" a .NET project. When I met the responsible developer, he told me that this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test Button" />
```

will render as an `<asp:button>`

I told him no, it will render a `<button>` or `<input>`.

Is there any source of clarification about this? Can you also  any help on how can I set a .NET server on my Windows machine, so I can test code?

I have WAMP installed & I want to run both, 'cause most of my work is on WAMP.

Thanks a lot everyone for the fast replies & links.

Comment: Then the "Responsible developer is very less experienced/naive and so dont seek his advice in future. The rendering wil be as an HTMl control, unless how does the browser know? There is no magic there. Its just a powerful framework called ASP.NET :)

Comment: actually he will be the developer i`ll be working with on this task :|

Comment: @Gabri: learn ASP.NET. its very easy. I think you may have to style that ASP.NET button. Apply CssClass="your class name" on it. Firebug will help you a lot.

Comment: @Gabri: to use .NET and PHP, the best way is to install IIS and then install php on iis. apache will be tougher to configure :)

Comment: @yetanothercoder I will tell the truth , i don`t love Microsoft :D. but maybe i`ll give it a try in the future. Firebug is already my friend :)

Comment: @Gabri: dont stop loving anything you dont know. :)

Comment: @yetanothercoder for me MS = IE & Windows both of them gives me a hard time , but the IIS i didnot knew about before it seems nice

Comment: Please give a meaningful Title to your question in context of your issue. "ASP.NET novice help" isn't very meaningful. Imagine everyone using Title like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup a .NET server I would take a look at the [Microsoft Webplatform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) as that will give you everything you need very easily including a Visual Studio Express.

As to asp.net controls they get rendered out as regular html like so

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1">
```

The [web forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) website will give you some more tips

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the code, just install [Microsoft® Visual Web Developer® 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/)

It has a buid-in server so you will be able to test the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

To run the project you can download Visual Studio Express, or purchase a version of Visual Studio.

In the end ASP.NET controls like `<ASP:Button>` will render as HTML elements as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, an ASP Button will render to an HTML input control.
Also, you might want to try out the free version of [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) for web.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click -> view source on his page and show him the actual markup of it rendering the `<input />` element.  Proof is in the source!

Answer (score 0):

An `<asp:Button />` will render as an `<input>` control.

If you need to style it, can't you just create a class.

```
.buttonStyle { whatever: style; }
```

Then your developer can just apply the style.

```
<asp:Button ID="button" CSSClass="buttonStyle" runat="server" />
```

[Express versions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) are also available as well.